# Unable to restore DB after Database change to Postgres (Django)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-database

I have migrated from SQLite to Postgres, but now I am unable to restore my data on Postgres, i am using Django *db-backup* package, it is giving me this error on *dbrestore* command

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\fooddelivery\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\fooddelivery\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\dbbackup\management\commands\dbrestore.py", line 53, in handle
    self._restore_backup()
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\dbbackup\management\commands\dbrestore.py", line 94, in _restore_backup
    self.connector.restore_dump(input_file)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\base.py", line 92, in restore_dump
    result = self._restore_dump(dump)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\postgresql.py", line 56, in _restore_dump
    stdout, stderr = self.run_command(cmd, stdin=dump, env=self.restore_env)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\postgresql.py", line 21, in run_command
    return super(PgDumpConnector, self).run_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\atifs\Documents\food_deliveryapp\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\base.py", line 150, in run_command
    raise exceptions.CommandConnectorError(
dbbackup.db.exceptions.CommandConnectorError: Error running:  psql  --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on --single-transaction postgres
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTOINCREMENT"
LINE 1: ...S "auth_group" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREM...
```

Comment: Well, a script intended for SQLite isn't compatiable with Postgres (e.g. Postgres uses `identity` columns, not `AUTOINCREMENT`). You will have to edit the script and change all SQLite specific syntax to Postgres syntax

Comment: i tried to change , but i now i am not even able to restore my dump file